# Swift NSTimer Pause Resume

Tags: swift, nstimer

I am programming with Swift, and I have a problem.
I am writing code using a timer using NSTimer, and I have succeeded in stopping the timer. I created a button to restart the timer, but I do not know how to enter the code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    /*Timer1*/
    var landmarkTime = 0
    var landmarkNSTimer = Timer()

    /*Timer3*/
    func landmarkTimer() {
        landmarkTime += 1
    }

    /*PauseButton*/
    @IBAction func PauseButton(_ sender: Any) {
        landmarkNSTimer.invalidate()
    }

    /*ResumeButton*/
    @IBAction func ResumeButton(_ sender: Any) {
        /*I want to restart the timer in this part, but I do not know what code to put in.*/
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        /*Timer2*/
        landmarkNSTimer = Timer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.landmarkTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        RunLoop.main.add(landmarkNSTimer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
    }
}
```

`/* ResumeButton */` This is a problem. I typed `/* Timer2 */` in this part, but I have an unknown problem and am looking for another code. Tell the new code to be entered in `/* ResumeButton */` so that the timer can be restarted.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timer

Comment: The "resume" code is the same as the code you have in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't pause the timer, you stopped it. If you read the documentation for `invalidate`, it says [emphasis added]:

> Stops the receiver from **ever firing again** and requests its removal from its run loop.

Timers don't pause; it's simply not part of their API. If you want a pause/resume behavior, there are a variety of ways to get it, including:

- Create a new timer when resuming.
- Set the `fireDate` to `Date.distantFuture` when pausing, then set it to some time in the near future when resuming.
- Use a boolean variable to indicate the paused state, and have your timer callback check that variable when the timer fires. If paused == true, do nothing.